# How to transfer frozen nfts in solana phantom wallet

Tags: blockchain, transfer, nft, solana-web3js, metaplex

When I transfer nfts on solana, "Account is frozen" error occurs.

https://magiceden.io/item-details/tXzY8BAEegYeiH2VzLr6XXA1ywtXVRFNYnANscobrAB
this is the nft, I want to transfer.

Some says that I have to use metaplex.
I don't what to do.

But it works very well on another nfts.
What am I gonna do with it?
Please help me.

Comment: I have the same problem here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77951517/how-to-transfer-frozen-nfts IDK how to do it

Answer (score 0):

This is a programmable NFT. They are always frozen and only thawed on transfer by the metaplex token metadata program.

It's correct that you will have to use metaplex functions for it. If you want to do it by code in JS you can use the umi library.

```js
import { transferV1 } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'

await transferV1(umi, {
  mint,
  authority: currentOwner,
  tokenOwner: currentOwner.publicKey,
  destinationOwner: newOwner.publicKey,
  tokenStandard: TokenStandard.NonFungible,
}).sendAndConfirm(umi)
```

https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/transfer